# Convert input str to int in python

Tags: python, math, structure, typeerror, conventions

I get the error code:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' in
>   its current state.

The problem is that I don't know how to convert user input expectations to integer from string format.

```
number = input ("Please guess what number I'm thinking of. HINT: it's between 1 and 30")
```

I've looked up how to do it but I couldn't find what I was looking for because I'm not sure how to word my question properly.

I've tried putting "`int`" after `number` and after `input` but it doesn't work. Not sure where to put it to get it to work.

Comment: When I put input(int)etc... it prints <class int> and I don't know what that means.

Comment: Just put `int` before `input`. E.g. `number=int(input("question"))`

Comment: This method also returns <class int> in the shell

Comment: Ah nevermind, I forgot to remove the 'int' AFTER the input part. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the input type is `string`. To convert it into `integer`, just put `int` before `input`. E.g.

```
number = int(input("Please guess what number I'm thinking of. HINT: it's between 1 and 30: "))
print(type(number))
```

Sample of the output:

```
Please guess what number I'm thinking of. HINT: it's between 1 and 30: 30
<class 'int'>   # it shows that the input type is integer
```

**ALTERNATIVE**

```
# any input is string
number = input("Please guess what number I'm thinking of. HINT: it's between 1 and 30: ")   
try:                      # if possible, try to convert the input into integer
    number = int(number)
except:                   # if the input couldn't be converted into integer, then do nothing
    pass
print(type(number))       # see the input type after processing
```

Sample of the output:

```
Please guess what number I'm thinking of. HINT: it's between 1 and 30: 25    # the input is a number 25
<class 'int'>   # 25 is possible to convert into integer. So, the type is integer

Please guess what number I'm thinking of. HINT: it's between 1 and 30: AAA   # the input is a number AAA
<class 'str'>   # AAA is impossible to convert into integer. So, the type remains string
```